# DjangoRestAPI filter a list field

Tags: python-3.x, django, api, django-rest-framework

in my DjangoRestAPI project i have 2 serialisers like this:

serializers.py

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Tags
        fields = ['tagkey', 'tagval']

    def create(self, validated_data):

        return Tags.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.tagkey = validated_data.get('tagkey', instance.tagkey)
        instance.tagval = validated_data.get('tagval', instance.tagval)

        instance.save()
        return instance


class ModvarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
    var_group = VarGroupSerializer(read_only=True)
    tag_var = TagSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ModbusVariable
        fields = ['id', 'short_name', 'uom', 'var_group', 'unit', 'writeable', 'value_class', 'address', 'bit_count', 'min_type','max_type', 'byte_order','function_code_read', 'is_quarterly', 'tag_var', 'owner']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ...
```

well now in my views.py i have to create a ModVar list with a filter also for tag_var value:

views.py

```
class ModvarsList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = ModbusVariable.objects.using(random.choice(replica_list)).all()
    serializer_class = ModvarSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
    # paginator = None
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = {
        'unit__port_id__master_id': ['exact'],
        'unit__port_id__master_id__short_name': ['exact'],
        'is_quarterly': ['exact'],
        'tag_var': ['exact']
    }
    search_fields = ['unit__port_id__master_id', 'unit__port_id__master_id__short_name', 'is_quarterly']
    ordering_fields = '__all__'
```

so if i run my API caall without filter i get this results:

[image]

but if i try to filter for example using tag_var="tagkey: site1" or just "site1" i ever get the error

> The value is not correct for tag_var filter

How can i expose just "key" and "value" field of tag_val value for filtering based on that values my API results?

So many thanks in advance
Manuel

Comment: Try to filter using `http://api-url/endpoint?tag_var__tagkey=site1` in api url

Comment: thanks but it does not filter, return ll data

Comment: Do you want to filter the content of `tag_var` field?

Comment: yes, for example every record with tag_var/tagval="string1" or tag_var/tagkey="test"

Comment: Then you need to implement this on `ModvarSerializer` with `serializers.MethodField() `. Take a look at similar topis  https://stackoverflow.com/a/68306842/7320870