# Django REST Framework, display specific foreign key data objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'll get straight to my point

Here is my API output:

[image]

In pictures, I need to display objects that have primary_placeholder set to True.
I can't find answer on how to do it, I've tried searching in REST Api documentation but nothing seems to work, it always displays every single picture

serializers.py:

[image]

views.py

[image]

Models.py (Theese two that I'm currently working with)
[image]

Does anyone know what is the easiest and fastest way to do it? I have absolutely no idea and I've been trying figure it out for about 2 days now.
Database currently has no pictures with primary_placeholder set to True if anyone is confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want to show product pictures with `primary_placeholder=True`, we can use `prefetch_related` with `Prefetch`, please [read this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related).
In your case above, i suggest:

views.py

```
from django.db import models
from your_app.models import Product, ProductPictures


class ProductList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        products = Product.objects.all().prefetch_related(
            models.Prefetch(
                "pictures",
                queryset=ProductPictures.objects.filter(primary_placeholder=True)
            )
        )
        serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Another suggest: In model `ProductPictures` field `model`, better if change the field name to `product`.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly the answer I've been looking for.

Answer (score 1):

write a serializer method field and filter products in it.

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    filtered_pictures = serializers.MethodField() 
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['brand','model','prize','filtered_pictures']
    def get_filtered_pictures(self,obj):
        if obj.pictures.exists():
            queryset = obj.pictures.filter(primary_placeholder=True)  
            return ProductPictureSerializer(queryset, many=True).data
        else:
            return None
```

Comment: This may be correct, but it will result in other problems with queryset performance. Maybe batter using .prefecth_related with Prefetch.